# Query runs endlessly and out of memory - MySQL 8.0.16 AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Can anybody help me with this query in MySQL 8.0.16? This query runs endlessly  on AWS RDS and gets out of memory and I guess the problem is all about UNION ALL and GROUP BY statements.

```
SELECT 
       SUM(`CONV`.`ELEGIVEL`) AS `ELEGIVEL`,
       SUM(`CONV`.`ADESAO`) AS `ADESAO`,
       `CONV`.`ano` AS `ano`,
       `CONV`.`mes` AS `mes`,
       `CONV`.`TIPO` AS `TIPO`
   FROM
       (


SELECT 
           SUM(`v`.`QuantidadeItem`) AS `ELEGIVEL`,
               NULL AS `ADESAO`,
               `v`.`ano` AS `ano`,
               `v`.`mes` AS `mes`,
               'BENCH' AS `TIPO`
       FROM
           `V_VENDAS_ELEGIVEIS` `v`
       WHERE
           ((`v`.`nome_emp` LIKE '%ESB%')
               AND (`v`.`data_lancamento` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT((NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))))
       GROUP BY `v`.`ano` , `v`.`mes` UNION ALL SELECT 
           NULL AS `ELEGIVEL`,
               COUNT(0) AS `ADESAO`,
               `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Ano` AS `ano`,
               `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Mes` AS `mes`,
               'BENCH' AS `TIPO`
       FROM
           `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`
       WHERE
           ((`V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`nome_emp` LIKE '%ESB%')
               AND (`V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`dataemissao` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT((NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))))
       GROUP BY `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Ano` , `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Mes` UNION ALL SELECT 
           SUM(`v`.`QuantidadeItem`) AS `ELEGIVEL`,
               NULL AS `ADESAO`,
               `v`.`ano` AS `ano`,
               `v`.`mes` AS `mes`,
               'BRAND' AS `TIPO`

       FROM
           `V_VENDAS_ELEGIVEIS` `v`
       WHERE
           (`v`.`data_lancamento` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT((NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
       GROUP BY `v`.`ano` , `v`.`mes` UNION ALL SELECT 
           NULL AS `ELEGIVEL`,
               COUNT(0) AS `ADESAO`,
               `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Ano` AS `ano`,
               `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Mes` AS `mes`,
               'BRAND' AS `TIPO`
       FROM
           `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`
       WHERE
           (`V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`dataemissao` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT((NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
       GROUP BY `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Ano` , `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Mes`

) `CONV`

GROUP BY `CONV`.`ano` , `CONV`.`mes`, `CONV`.`TIPO`
```

If I split the query above into one query per time like the code below, the result is quite quickly.

```
SELECT 
       SUM(`BENCH`.`ELEGIVEL`) AS `ELEGIVEL`,
       SUM(`BENCH`.`ADESAO`) AS `ADESAO`,
       `BENCH`.`ano` AS `ano`,
       `BENCH`.`mes` AS `mes`,
       'BENCHMARK' AS `TIPO`
   FROM
       (SELECT 
           SUM(`v`.`QuantidadeItem`) AS `ELEGIVEL`,
               NULL AS `ADESAO`,
               `v`.`ano` AS `ano`,
               `v`.`mes` AS `mes`
       FROM
           `V_VENDAS_ELEGIVEIS` `v`
       WHERE
           ((`v`.`nome_emp` LIKE '%ESB%')
               AND (`v`.`data_lancamento` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT((NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))))
       GROUP BY `v`.`ano` , `v`.`mes` UNION ALL SELECT 
           NULL AS `ELEGIVEL`,
               COUNT(0) AS `ADESAO`,
               `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Ano` AS `ano`,
               `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Mes` AS `mes`
       FROM
           `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`
       WHERE
           ((`V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`nome_emp` LIKE '%ESB%')
               AND (`V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`dataemissao` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT((NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))))
       GROUP BY `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Ano` , `V_SEGUROS_ADESAO`.`Mes`) `BENCH`
   GROUP BY `BENCH`.`ano` , `BENCH`.`mes`
```

The server is based on AWS RDS. I didn´t change any parameter group, it´s the default.mysql8.0 parameter.

It´s a db.t3.medium instance and it has 4Gb of RAM

Comment: Please re-write your title as a sentence and not with all caps. No need to shout.

Answer (score 0):

The nested SELECT statements with grouping at each level is too complicated and inefficient.  I would strongly suggest re-designing your logic into a Stored Procedure where you could use temp tables and a combination of simpler commands to gather your data one step at a time.